# How can I weight ordinal observations and reduce them to one statistic?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, descriptive-statistics, weighted-data, survey-weights, inequality

It will be a complicated question and I try to briefly explain. I am studying on educational inequalities. The survey I use for analysis incudes ordinal variables and the education degree which represent equality is elementary-middle school-high school and university (coded as 1-2-3-4).

I can perform my analysis of educational inequality by directly converting this ordinal data to cardinal data. But what I want to do is to make the educational variable more qualified. For this, I want to include other variables and weight like education degree (ordinal variable), completed courses (ordinal variable), number of foreign languages ​​(ordinal variable) representation of education as a single variable. I want to all these variables represent educational quality as one variable.

Is this statistically possible? If possible, can you suggest a helpful resource? Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: This is not a statistical question. You can create any combination you want of the study data. Right now: education is ordinal (1, 2, 3, 4). But you could, e.g. take the interaction of education and sex to have M1, M2, M3, and M4 as well as F1, F2, F3, and F4 (or any such combo). In models for categorical outcomes, you're done. For ordinal models like linear regression, you simply consider the interaction. But your question lacks scope and purpose to get meaningful answers.

Comment: You can contrive some sort of 'index' of educational accomplishment that includes whatever information you suppose is relevant. // With such diverse information as foreign languages and numbers of courses completed, you may have some trouble deciding how much weight to put on each when you make your index. (Is fluency in Urdu and Ukrainian equal to three courses in math? Does Spanish count more than Swedish? Does history count more than physics?) // My question is why you want to do this. Is the current scale using 1 = elementary, through 4 = university not turning out to be useful?